# ZXing BarCode Scanner Only Scans App Barcodes

Tags: java, android, android-intent, zxing

I have leveraged the ZXing barcode scanner intent, but it will only scan App barcodes (the barcodes that you take a picture of and it installs the app on your phone).  I want it to be able to scan the barcodes of everyday objects, such as those found on soda cans and boxes of food.  When I put it up to a normal barcode it won't detect it.

Here is the code for when I call the intent.

```
            public void onClick(View v) {

            //Link to the Barcode Scanner intent.
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");         

            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Blrfl's answer should be correct, but you are mistaken that QR codes are only used for "app barcodes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave out the `SCAN_MODE` extra and it will scan anything it understands.

Comment: To expand on this answer - The "App barcode" you're referring to is actually called a QR Code.  That's the square full of smaller black squares.  When you send the scan_mode of QR_CODE_MODE, you're telling ZXing to *only* search for that type of barcode, not the kind you're wanting to scan (vertical black bars).